# How to access project structure to add jar files on MacBook?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I'm used to using IntelliJ on Windows. For work purposes I also need to use it on a MacBook and I'm completely lost. First time using MacOS.

I have IntelliJ installed and running. No menu bar! I need to access the Project Structure dialog so I can add the missing jar files for Selenium.

What's Mac equivalent to CTRL+ALT+Shift+S? Also is there a way on Mac to enable the menu bar?

Thanks in advance!

-Mac Noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a project tab on the left hand side of the window that will show the file tree if you click it. From there, you can drag and drop.

To access the project structure you can go `File` --> `Project Structure` or do `cmd+;` (for me)

As for the menu bar, I think you are talking about the `File/Edit/View` bar at the top of the screen (very top, right next to the apple logo).